# How to use a cell-renderer without specifying a field in ag-grid

Tags: datatables, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to use the last column as the expand row functionality. For this I'm using master/detail. The last column of master will just be an arrow down icon which on click will show the detail row. I'm unable to add a last column without providing a field name. The column is rendered empty. How can I use something like this:

```
{
   headerName: '',
   field: "", // as not associated to any column data
   cellRenderer: "agGroupCellRenderer"
}
```

Comment: what happens if you remove `field: ""` entirely, does it not render? Have you tried `cellRendererFramework` and passing your custom callback that does what you need

Comment: No. The column doesn't render unless a genuine field ( present in the data ) has been provided.

Comment: Try using the fieldName with existing field and couple that with cellRendererFramework with your custom callback and see if that serves the purpose

Comment: see this example that I just created, https://plnkr.co/edit/4CrQn6?p=preview it replaces field Value with custom text `DOWN` that I gave. Basically you would do the same except provide custom HTML or SVG or IMG instead.

Comment: @Rikin it's still being mapped to a field. Let's say there's 5 fields  and I want to add a edit button on the 6th column without mapping it to any field.

Comment: what do you use this in, what framework, React?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working example that you may be looking for, I did not had to rely on `field` for it. https://plnkr.co/edit/RxjZ9rUt7HUhlw5ejUd6?p=preview
Example is in ReactJS ag-grid code but the same thing applies to any framework as ag-grid relies on the columnDefinition array that you pass it in.

Here's the code change:

```
{
  colId: "action",  // optional
  headerName: "Action", // set it to single space if you dont want any text
  cellRendererFramework: (params) => <button onClick={() => (console.log(params), params.node.setSelected(true))}>+</button>, // this can be your any custom function
  suppressSorting: true,  // sorting for this field dont make sense, but optional
},
```

Hope that helps.